# SoundManager and monitorenter and monitorexit

Tags: android, monitor, android-audiomanager

I try to control sound with monitorenter and monitorexite this the code i use but this not work for me these erorrs shown : monitorenter cannot be resolved to a variable , monitorenter cannot be resolved to a variable, localObject cannot be resolved to a variable

```
 public static SoundManager getInstance()
 {
  monitorenter;
    try
    {
      if (_instance == null)
        _instance = new SoundManager();
      SoundManager localSoundManager = _instance;
      monitorexit;
      return localSoundManager;
    }
    finally
    {
      localObject = finally;
      monitorexit;
    }
    throw localObject;
}
```